# Deserialize a string

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Currently I'm using this code to deserialize a file

```
            StreamReader str = new StreamReader(reply);
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(imginfo));
            imginfo res = (imginfo)xSerializer.Deserialize(str);
```

How should I modify the code if `reply` is a string and not a path to an xml file?

Comment: Would the reply contain the xml file as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you use an `XmlReader` chained to a `StringReader`:

```
imginfo res;
using(var sr = new StringReader(xml)) // "xml" is our string containing xml
using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) {
    res = (imginfo)xSerializer.Deserialize(xr);
}
//... use "res"
```

or as Anders notes:

```
imginfo res;
using(var sr = new StringReader(xml)) // "xml" is our string containing xml
    res = (imginfo)xSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
//... use "res"
```

Comment: The XmlSerializer takes any text reader as an argument, what is the difference here when using an XmlReader in between? (Given we don't want to pass any XmlReaderSettings).

Comment: @Anders fair enough - we can probs. remove a step and `.Deserialize(sr)`. Force of habit ;p

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringReader` instead of `StreamReader`. No other change needed.

Comment: Personally I'd argue that the code *in the question* already needs changes (`using` etc)

Comment: @Marc - Yes. Very much so. I was thinking step #1.